# div no se ubica en donde debería - position absolute

Tags: html, css

quiero ubicar un div, en las coordenadas.

Me lo ubica más arriba y más a la izquierda de las coordenadas.

En el caso de agregar un "circle" por ejemplo, en el svg, si me toma bien las coordenadas. Pero con el div, no encuentro la forma

HTML:

```
<div id="diver" class="zoom" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                <svg id="usersvg" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 280" height="100%" width="100%" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
                    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
                    <polyline id="polyline" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1"/>
                    <image id="imglote" xlink:href="resources/img.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100%"></image>

                </svg>
                <div class="divinfo"></div>
                <div class="zoom-svg-zoom zoom-svg-zoom-in"> + </div>
                <div class="zoom-svg-zoom zoom-svg-zoom-rst"> = </div>
                <div class="zoom-svg-zoom zoom-svg-zoom-out"> - </div>

            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.divinfo {
        background-color: blue;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 200px;
        top: 80px;
    }
.zoom {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 4px solid #333;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hola @Dante. Probé el código que has publicado acá y he observado que la figura se ubica en las coordenadas que le indicas. Por lo tanto, ¿podrías ser más específico e indicar dónde quieres ubicar la figura?

Comment: Si, disculpas. El elemento se tiene q ubicar en las coordenadas X-Y pero del DIV "diver", no del "body" en general.